# Back up most recently modified file within directory

Tags: windows-7, backup

I have a collection of directories.

I need a one-click way of backing up to an external drive, but only the most recent file within each directory.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why need to differentiate files?  Backup system won't backup another copy of a file, new files get added, old ones that match are skipped.  But if you're rolling your own backup, I like rsync, since it'll just add new files and skip existing.  Of course, you could do some fancy scripting using find, ls (sort by date), tail (or head) and probably xargs for simplicity.

Comment: @lornix The OP is on Windows.

Comment: @sihck: I know. There exists rsync for windows, and I prefer a straight copy type backup rather than being encumbered with some proprietary new-fangled compression scheme that won't be compatible with next month's update.  KISS always works.  But if OP was using something more.... scriptable... it's almost (almost!) trivial.  Hey, how about powershell?  It's like bash in .net (just kill me now!)